# How wave speed affects perception?

Tags: waves, acoustics, biology, perception

If there were 2 sound waves with the same wavelength and amplitude, but different speeds, how would my perception of the waves vary? How would my perception vary if they were light waves instead of sound?

Comment: If the waves are traveling through the same medium, how can they have different speeds?

Answer (score 1):

They would be waves traveling through different media with their frequencies set so that they have the same wavelength. So you would see them as different colors or hear them as different pitches.